# CSS not inserted properly in a webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack

- I am using webpack to bundle a reactjs app to production.
- I have successfully built the project and the site is working properly.
- I am using extract-text-plugin to convert my css files to a single bundle, style-loader and css loader.
- The problem is, when rendered on browser, there are a lot of extra style sheet declarations in the html head instead of just one bundle.min.css
- Why is this happening?Can this be because some css gets inlined in js?Also we have css linked from other dependent projects. Can extract-text-plugin bundle this too or could that be the reason?

[image]

- the config file is the following

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const validate = require('webpack-validator');
const parts = require('./libs/parts');

const PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'src/client/index.tsx'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
  codepath: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
};

const common = {
  entry: {
    app: PATHS.app
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/index.html'),
      inject: 'body'
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    root: [path.resolve('./src')],
    extensions: ['', '.jsx', '.js', '.tsx', '.ts']
  },
  postcss: [
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
};

var config;

switch (process.env.npm_lifecycle_event) {
  case 'build':
    config = merge(
      common,
      parts.babelTranspile(PATHS.codepath),
      parts.setupCSS(PATHS.codepath),
      parts.setupLESS(PATHS.codepath),
      parts.minify()
    );
    break;
  default:
    config = merge(
      common,
      parts.babelTranspile(PATHS.codepath),
      //parts.setupCSS(PATHS.codepath),
      //parts.setupLESS(PATHS.codepath),
      parts.setFreeVariable(
        'process.env.NODE_ENV',
        'production'
      ),
      parts.minify(),
      parts.extractCSS(PATHS.codepath),
      parts.extractLESS(PATHS.codepath)
    )
}

module.exports = validate(config);
```

- And this is the file where we keep all the plugins and loaders.

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

exports.babelTranspile = function(paths) {
    return {
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    loaders: ['babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015', 'ts'],
                    include: paths
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

exports.setupCSS = function(paths) {
    return {
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loaders: ['style', 'css']
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

exports.setupLESS = function(paths) {
    return {
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.less$/,
                    loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'less']
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

exports.minify = function() {
    return {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                compress: {
                    warnings: false
                }
            })
        ]
    };
}

exports.setFreeVariable = function(key, value) {
    const env = {};
    env[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    return {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin(env)
        ]
    };
}

exports.extractCSS = function(paths) {
    return {
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css')
                    //include: paths
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin('css/bundle.min.css')
        ]
    };
}

exports.extractLESS = function(paths) {
    return {
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.less$/,
                    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css', 'postcss', 'less')
                    //include: paths
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin('css/bundle.min.css')
        ]
    };
}
```